# Why my DIV doesn't respond to click?

Tags: jquery, function, html

That my Javascript for click

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".role").click(function () {
        alert("idiot");
    });
});  
</script>
```

my CSS for the DIV "role"

```
{
position: absolute;
 width: 50px;
 min-height:20px;
 height:auto;
 border:1px solid #000; 
 word-wrap: break-word; 
 float:left;
 font-size:12px;
  z-index: 30;
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-left:3px;
}
```

This is the HTML

```
<div class="role" align="center"  >Gate Keeper</div>
```

How to call the function of the clicking on the HTML?

This is my Jfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/6CWUq/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to include the jQuery framework in your jsfiddle. Just pick the version of jQuery you want to be included and your code will work as expected:

[image]

Comment: ohhhh Sorry  overlook it

Comment: Always remember to check the Firebug/Inspector console for error messages.  It can be accessed by F12.  In this case `$ is undefined` is a dead giveaway that jQuery isn't loaded.

Comment: @ryan: And since you're using `ready`, you can switch off jsFiddle's brain-dead default of including the script `onload` and use `No wrap` instead. (Or better yet, use `No wrap - body` and don't even use `ready.`)